VRF subscription sepolita testnet
i'm new on ethereum.
I followed the following guide:
https://docs.chain.link/vrf/v2-5/subscription/get-a-random-number
and everything seems to have gone fine.
but after 15 hours the process is still pending:
https://vrf.chain.link/sepolia/11241479695975836523073945322506188019636303675590468335590554157603193037413
Can anyone tell me why?
tanks, regards

Your subscription is pending because your balance is insufficient as mentioned here. The message says "This subscription has a pending transaction due to low balance."
You'll need to add LINK tokens and Sepolia ETH on your account.
You can get the tokens at this link.
The detailed steps that you need to do are mentioned here. As mentioned here, you need to fund the subscription first.
Please let me know if you have any questions. Feel free to mark this as the answer if it helps you.
Edit 1: Accoring to current rates, you'll need to add 5 LINK or around 0.03 ETH to fund the contract. The acutal cost that will be deducted from the balance will be 0.06 LINK or 0.000247 ETH according to what you have funded.

0
Tanks very much Pankaj.
but i used 20 LINKS (videotutorial use 5 LINKS).
Do you know how many LINKS need to be used to complete the transaction?

I have Edited the answer to mention that. Let me know if you still have any doubts.

ok.. tanks i have add 10 TOKENS: https://vrf.chain.link/sepolia/11241479695975836523073945322506188019636303675590468335590554157603193037413     let's see if it works... thank you very much

ok.. it worked... thank you very much

Great. Do mark my answer as the correct answer, to help others refer to it whenver needed in future.
